# How to get speed measure $m(dx)$, scale function $s$, and killing measure $k(dx)$ of a diffusion from the infinitesimal generator?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

This question comes from P13 and P17 of the book [Andrei N.Borodin and Paavo Salminen](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=8cZrllyXfOUC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=Andrei%20N.Borodin%20and%20Paavo%20Salminen&ots=VDvtxpIWm1&sig=_C4_7rZfM7zYWLroOkzG4NVQjyM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Andrei%20N.Borodin%20and%20Paavo%20Salminen&f=false).

Page [P13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHq9u.png) defines the speed measure $m(dx)$, the scale function $s$, and the killing measure $k(dx)$.

Case 9 on [P17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaGmK.png):

"We consider here the special case in which the basic characteristics are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure and have smooth derivatives. In other words,

$m(dx)=m(x)dy,k(dx)=k(x)dx,s(x)=\int^x s'(y)dy$,

where $m,s'$ are continuous and positive, and $k$ is continuous and non-negative. Morever, if $s''$ is continous, then the second order infinitesimal generator $$\mathcal{G}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}a(x)^2f''(x)+b(x)f'(x)-c(x)f(x),$$

The functions $a, b, c$ are the infinitesimal parameters of $X$.
"

My question is, based on the statement above, how to get the following results:

$m(x)=2a^{-2}(x)e^{B(x)}, s'(x)=e^{-B(x)},k(x)=2a^{-2}(x)c(x)e^{B(x)}, B(x)=\int^x 2a^{-2}(y) b(y)dy$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, you are equating coefficients in the two different representations of the generator:
$$
{1\over m(x)}\left[\left({f'(x)\over s(x)}\right)'-k(x)f(x)\right] = {1\over 2}a(x)^2f''(x)+b(x)f'(x)-c(x)f(x).
$$
The left side expands out to
$$
{1\over m(x)}\left[{f''(x)\over s(x)}-{s'(x)f'(x)\over s(x)^2}-k(x)f(x)\right].
$$
Therefore
$$
{a^2\over 2} = {1\over ms},\quad b=-{s'\over ms^2},\quad c={k\over m}.
$$
Dividing the first two of these:
$$
(\log s)'={s'\over s} =-{2b\over a^2},
$$
so
$$
s(x) = C_1\exp\left(-2\int^xb(t)/a(t)^2 dt\right)=C_1e^{-B(x)}.
$$
Choosing the constant of integration $C_1$ to be $1$, the rest follows easily.

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain the generator of the left side for the first equation. How to get it? Is it possible to give some reference?

Comment: This is Feller's form of the generator.  You can read all about it in the book "Diffusion Processes and their Sample Paths" by Ito & McKean. Also in "Brownian Motion and Diffusion" by D.A. Freedman or "Essentials of Brownian Motion and Diffusion" by F.B. Knight.